# Saving values from selectlistitem to viewmodel

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, razor

I have problem with selectListItem class.
(I can load data to list items in form, but cant save data only from list items when submiting )
When i submit form and send data from viewModel to controller selected selectlistitem attributes  remain as null values(PoslovnicaID =0, poslovnice= null) in viewModel.
 here is some code:
 attributes from view model

```
[Required]
public int PoslovnicaID { get; set; }
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Polje je obavezno.")]
public List<SelectListItem> poslovnice { get; set; }
```

code from view

```html
<div class="col-md-12 form-group">
  <label asp-for="poslovnice">Odabir poslovnice</label>
  <select name=""
    asp-for="PoslovnicaID"
    asp-items="poslovnice"
    class="form-control">
    <option selected disabled>Odabir poslovnice</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Can you tell me if i am missing something obvious
i appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model binding is based on the name attribute. You should remove `name=""` in the select tag, since `asp-for="PoslovnicaID"` will render it as `name="PoslovnicaID"`.

Besides, the form will only submit the value of selected option(PoslovnicaID), it will be binded to `PoslovnicaID` in the ViewModel, so `poslovnice` will be null and should be null.

A simple test:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    ViewModel viewModel = new ViewModel
    {
        PoslovnicaID = 1,
        poslovnice = new List<SelectListItem> 
        { 
            new SelectListItem{ Text = "AAA", Value = "1"},
            new SelectListItem{ Text = "BBB", Value = "2"},
            new SelectListItem{ Text = "CCC", Value = "3"},
        }

    };
    return View(viewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Edit(ViewModel viewModel)
{
        
    return View();
}
```

View:

```
@model ViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h1>Index</h1>

<form asp-action="Edit" method="post">
    <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
        <label asp-for="poslovnice">Odabir poslovnice</label>
        <select name="poslovnice"
                asp-for="PoslovnicaID" 
                asp-items="Model.poslovnice"
                class="form-control">
            <option selected disabled>Odabir poslovnice</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-danger" />
</form>
```

Result:

[image]